# PS query to retrieve data from old environment via Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am running the below script with the intention to get all users that are currently enabled, password never expire, password last set and last logon date and it works just fine. I would like to add to the data the group those users/accounts belong to or any other information so i can contact their respective teams/managers to request clean up or decomm.

```
get-aduser -filter {Enabled -eq $TRUE} -properties passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires, lastlogonDate |
    Select-Object Name, passwordlastset, Passwordneverexpires, lastlogonDate, DistinguishedName |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\passlastset_enabledusers.csv'
```

How would i add this to this query. As it is works great but thought to avoid manual labor :)
Any advise? Thank you.

Comment: to get user's membership you can query the `memberOf` attribute, to get the user's manager, you can query the user's `manager` attribute (assuming its set up this way in your domain)

Answer (score 0):

I personally like adding all of my properties to an array beforehand. Helps when you want to expand onto it in the future. As for the members groups, you need to create you own expression or else when you export to a csv it'll just say `[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection]`. Also added the users manager as one of the properties it selects.

```
$properties = @(
    "passwordlastset",
    "passwordneverexpires",
    "lastlogonDate",
    "memberof"
)


Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $true} -properties $properties |
    Select-Object Name, passwordlastset, Passwordneverexpires, lastlogonDate, DistinguishedName, Manager, @{Name='MemberOf';Expression={$_.MemberOf -join ';'}} |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\passlastset_enabledusers.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Another tidbit I forgot to add, querying for the users `lastlogondate` is a little tricky. It'll return a date for some and nothing for some other users. Depending on how many DCs you have, the command will grab the info off the nearest DC. So if the user authenticated with a DC in Seattle and you're in Dallas it'll show that user as if they've never logged on.